# In Bash: grep command output that isn't stored in a file, and store it in a file?

Tags: bash

In reference to [My orginial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399293/how-can-i-generalize-this-to-loop-over-multiple-inputs-bash-arrays/52401535?noredirect=1#comment91836633_52401535), this will be used in my script.

Basically, I run commands to provision CNAME's for domains to validate the domains for TLS. When the command `provision-cert test.com.json` is run it will output the contents below. Doesn't store them, only prints them in the console.

```
Determining SubjectAlternateNames for domain test.com
SubjectAlternateNames for domain test.com are:
    test.com
     *.test.com
Requesting Certificate for domain test.com
Certificate for domain test.com has ARN: arn:tmp:tmp:ran-loc- 
1:randomstring:certificate/randomstring

Settings tags on certificate for domain test.com
Retrieving DNS records required for validation for arn:tmp:tmp:ran-loc- 
1:randomstring:certificate/randomstring

Please add these records to DNS to complete validation
     _randomstring.test.com. IN CNAME _randomstring.validations.net.
Certificate needs to complete domain validation
```

I'm trying to grep the text `Please add these records to DNS to complete validation` and the line below it `_randomstring.test.com. IN CNAME _randomstring.tmp-validations.net.` into a .txt file multiples times but I don't want it to overwrite whats already been inserted into the .txt file from previous runs. It will run `provision-cert` 6 times so essentially I need to to grep each cname after it runs the command `provision-cert`.

I have tried `provision-cert test.com | grep "Please add these records to DNS to complete validation" -A 1  > file.txt` but it just freezes.

(I already have my statements in place, I just need to figure out the grep command, and then add it)

Is this possible?

Comment: What are you stuck with? What have you tried? If the problem is getting lines *after* a match, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274127/how-do-you-grep-a-file-and-get-the-next-5-lines/19274215

Comment: I have tried using `provision-cert test.com | grep "Please add these records to DNS to complete validation" -A 1  > file.txt` but it just freezes on the command.

~Added to question~

Comment: Does it output anything at all after you hit enter?

Comment: No, well I mean it created the file.txt but its empty. I found the answer though. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Found that `provision-cert test.com >> file.txt` successfully sent the output to a .txt file.

Then adding the command `grep "Please add these records to DNS to complete validation" -A 1 file.txt`

[Answer found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file/420983).

Comment: This would not appear to match the specified pattern and find the line below it

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but this finds information from a file and outputs it to a non-file, which is exactly the opposite of what the question asks for. `provision-cert test.com | grep "Please add these records to DNS to complete validation" -A 1  >> file.txt` really should be working. If you want to debug why it isn't, you can use `provision-cert test.com | tee temporary.txt | grep ... > file` to dump the command's output both before and after the grep and see if maybe it's in a different format than it shows interactively

Comment: I see, I will give that a go and see why its not working.